# Google Rich Snippets for iPhone apps isn't working

Tags: iphone, html, rich-snippets

I've setup the code for Google's Rich Snippets for my iPhone app [yycParking](http://randomtype.ca/projects/yyc-parking-app/) on my website. The relevant HTML looks like this:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SoftwareApplication">
  <!-- ... -->
  <h2 class="txt-align-center" itemprop="description">
    <strong>yycParking</strong> provides real time updates of parking in downtown Calgary
  </h2>
  <!-- ... -->
  <div class="two-column last">
    <!-- ... -->
      <p>We created <strong itemprop="name">yycParking</strong> to enhance a service provided by ...</p>
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
  <div class="two-column last txt-align-right">
    <!-- ... -->
      <a title="Download the YYC Parking App from the iTunes store now" href="http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/yycparking/id460852653?mt=8" target="_blank" itemprop="url">
        <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-436" title="app-store-badge" src="http://randomtype.ca/cms/assets/app-store-badge.png" alt="" />
      </a>
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
  <p>
    <meta itemprop="image" content="http://randomtype.ca/cms/assets/app-icon-124x124.png" />
  </p>
</div>
```

You'll see from the above HTML that I've included the following elements:

- Schema: `itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SoftwareApplication"`
- Description: `itemprop="description"`
- Name: `itemprop="name"`
- URL: `itemprop="url"`
- Image: `itemprop="image"`

From reading the [rich snippet software application specs](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=1645432) I believe I've hit the 4 required items, and properly identified the schema I'm following.

Running it through the [Rich Snippet testing tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http%3A%2F%2Frandomtype.ca%2Fprojects%2Fyyc-parking-app%2F&view=) I get a result that doesn't identify the snippet as an iPhone app, and skips out the nice image like "Cut the Rope" gets.

Am I missing something? I want to dominate the Calgary parking market - but Google is holding me back!1 :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems, you're missing a *price* and an *average rating*.
I have no clue if there's a strict definition of what's required and what's not, but adding these two solved the problem for me.

You might also want to consider adding some more information, such as OS and version.

You can see a working example [here](http://jenox.net/test_suite/richsnippet.html).

```
<dl>
    <dt>Updated:</dt>
    <dd><time itemprop="datePublished">September 29, 2011</time></dd>

    <dt>Current Version:</dt>
    <dd itemprop="softwareVersion">1.1.1</dd>

    <dt itemprop="operatingSystems" content="iOS">Requires iOS:</dt>
    <dd>4.0 and up</dd>

    <dt>Size:</dt>
    <dd itemprop="fileSize">14.2 MB</dd>

    <dt>Price:</dt>
    <dd itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <span itemprop="price">9.99$</span>
    </dd>

    <dt>Average Rating:</dt>
    <dd itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
        <span itemprop="ratingValue">3.6</span>
        (in <span itemprop="ratingCount">931728</span> ratings)
    </dd>
</dl>
```

**PS:** I'm not an expert on this topic, I just edited the Cut the Rope page and kept testing until the code was minimal but it still worked. :P

Comment: Brilliant!! That's awesome, and I really appreciate the effort. I totally didn't think of creating another page and pairing down cut the rope to test it. Bounty well earned!

Comment: Yay, just earned my second bounty! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

The actual "error" seems to be an bug with the Testing Tool. But, I looked at the "Cut the rope" example you mentioned and what's actually pulling the image and other formats is the [Open Graph protocol](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/):

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Cut the Rope" />
<meta property="og:type" content="game" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://chillingo.com/media/games/small/240x100_cuttherope.png" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Chillingo">
```

Comment: I'll update my html with your code and see if that changes anything.

Comment: It doesn't appear that the Open Graph code made a difference.

Comment: Well... are we talking about the [404 page you linked](http://chillingo.com/sku.htm?sid=344) or the [Cut the Rope](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.zeptolab.ctr.paid) one? CTR does not have any og:'s.